# Tuple appears in my code somehow, while I am working with lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

So here's the code. It take the "field", which is two-dimensional array (list of lists) and checks if any of the rows (lists) in it have 3 or more same tiles in a row and changes them to "0".
For example, `["B","G","R","R","R","B"]` becomes `["B","G","0","0","0","B"]`.

The problem is that it returns me

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

on line `row[each] = "0"`.

I am only starting with Python and I've never really seen tuples before. Also checking all the lists with `type()` always returned `<type 'list'>`

My questions are:

1. What exactly in this code makes tuple?
2. How do I do this code without tuples?

```
for row in field:
    tile = 0
    while tile < 6:
        next_tile = tile + 1
        while next_tile < 6:
            if row[next_tile] != row[tile]:
                break
            else:
                next_tile += 1
        if next_tile - tile >=3:
            for each in range(tile,next_tile):
                row[each] = "0"
        tile = next_tile
```

Here's the field generator code:

```
field = [[0 for x in range(6)] for x in range(6)] 
options = { 0 : "R", 1 : "G", 2 : "B", 3 : "S"}
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        field[i][j] = options[random.randint(0,3)]
return field
```

**Edit:**
Ok, it looks like when I call zip(*field) to transpose field, it take my array of arrays and turns it into array of tuples. So now I need to convert each row to list with `list()`, right?

Comment: I'd dare say that your `field` is not a list of lists but a list of tuples. Or maybe a tuple or tuples? At least some of its elements is a tuple. Note that in Python lists are not homogeneous, so you can have a list of lists. If you want to try it, please add `print(row)` just before the error line and post the results.

Comment: Please also show how your getting feild ?

Comment: `['R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'G', 'G']  

<type 'list'>

['R', '0', 'S', 'S', 'G', 'G']
<type 'list'>
['R', '0', '0', 'S', 'G', 'G']
<type 'list'>`
The funny thing is that it looks like it changes first two characters just fine, but struggles with third one

Comment: When I run this code, having defined `field = [["B","G","R","R","R","B"], ["B","G","R","R","R","B"]]`, I get the desired result: `[['B', 'G', '0', '0', '0', 'B'], ['B', 'G', '0', '0', '0', 'B']]`. Check your `field` - there must be a tuple there somewhere. Easiest way to find out would be to add a  `try/except` block around the failing assignment and print `row` if the exception is triggered.

Comment: Nothing in this code is creating tuples; the moment you see the exception `row` **must *already* be a tuple**.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to have a complete example that exhibits the problem.  I've cobbled together an example gleaned from your code and comments:

```
import random

field = [[0 for x in range(6)] for x in range(6)] 
options = { 0 : "R", 1 : "G", 2 : "B", 3 : "S"}
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        field[i][j] = options[random.randint(0,3)]

field = zip(*field)

print field

for row in field:
    tile = 0
    while tile < 6:
        next_tile = tile + 1
        while next_tile < 6:
            if row[next_tile] != row[tile]:
                break
            else:
                next_tile += 1
        if next_tile - tile >=3:
            for each in range(tile,next_tile):
                row[each] = "0"
        tile = next_tile

print field
```

This returns the following error:

```
[('G', 'S', 'R', 'S', 'R', 'G'), ('B', 'B', 'G', 'R', 'G', 'S'), ('B', 'G', 'R', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'G', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'R'), ('R', 'S', 'R', 'R', 'G', 'B'), ('G', 'G', 'G', 'S', 'S', 'G')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\dev\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\metolone\Desktop\x.py", line 24, in <module>
    row[each] = "0"
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

As you can see, field contains tuples now, so the fix is to convert them back to lists:

```
field = [list(r) for r in zip(*field)]
```

With this change, the output is:

```
[['S', 'S', 'B', 'G', 'R', 'G'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'S', 'B', 'G'], ['G', 'R', 'G', 'G', 'S', 'S'], ['G', 'B', 'S', 'G', 'G', 'G'], ['S', 'G', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'R'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'R', 'G', 'B']]
[['S', 'S', 'B', 'G', 'R', 'G'], ['0', '0', '0', 'S', 'B', 'G'], ['G', 'R', 'G', 'G', 'S', 'S'], ['G', 'B', 'S', '0', '0', '0'], ['S', 'G', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'R'], ['0', '0', '0', 'R', 'G', 'B']]
```